# How can i specify R code in the data files in R package

Tags: r, package

In my R package, I want R to load some data from an external server to main memory. Looking around i found the option of plain R files in the data file section of a package - http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages.

But then i couldnt find literature on how the R code will work in the data file section of a package nor how to invoke it.

It would be useful if someone can point me to a sample package too.

Comment: Keep reading.  A few default formats are automatically recognised.

Comment: by R Code , i am not expecting data itself but ability to specify a code that would import data from an external source , say from a nosql external database. Correct me if  i am wrong

Comment: You don't really explain your situation, but I doubt data files are what you want - the R code will be run _once_, when the package is built (or maybe installed).